# Ruby checkout button for Stripe API issue?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have two products right now on my index and some reason the second product `checkout button` will not work. But if I press it and then press the first checkout button it works. The params are passing correctly to the controller.  Why is this happening?

product(index code)

```
<div class="container">
  <% @product.each do |product| %>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><%=product.name%></h5>
            <h5 class="card-title">1:1 Personal Training Gold</h5>
            <ul>
              <li>Unlimited Sessions Per week</li>
              <li>Daily Check-ins</li>
              <li>Nutriton</li>
                <ul>
                  <li>Customized Meal Plans</li>
                  <li>Adjustment To Macros</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
            <p>$<%= product.price %></p>
            <%=button_to 'Buy Now', checkout_create_path, params: {id: product.id, price: product.price, stripe_price_id: product.stripe_price_id}, id: 'checkout-button', class: 'btn btn-primary', remote: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

checkout controller

```
def create
  Rails.logger.debug "params: #{params}"
  price_id = params[:stripe_price_id]
  @session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    mode: 'subscription',
    line_items: [{
      quantity: 1,
      price: price_id,
    }],
    #mode: 'payment',
    success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/checkout/success',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/checkout/failure',
  })
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
var stripe = Stripe("<%= Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:public] %>");
var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
    // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
    // available to this file, so you can provide it as argument here
    // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
    sessionId: '<%= @session.id %>'
  }).then(function (result) {
    // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
    // error, display the localized error message to your customer
    // using `result.error.message`.
    console.log(result.error.message);
  });
    console.log(result.error.message);
});
```

Comment: Its because you have duplicate IDs. When you have several elements with the same ID `document.getElementsById` will usually return the first one. Its also invalid HTML. The code doesn't actually make sense though. Your JS.erb template is evaluated after the user clicks the button and the ajax call completes - yet you're adding an onclick handler so that nothing will happen until the user click it again.

Comment: @max thank you for pointing that out. I fixed my create.js.erb file. It is working as expected now. I believe that js code from straight from Stripe API docs.

Comment: Another huge problem here is that you're taking the product price from the frontend. This lets a malicous user tamper with it and set any price they want. You should just be taking a product id and looking up the price on the backend. Stripe isn't really my area of expertise but I can tell you this is not how you want to setup a checkout system.

Comment: @max yeah, I have changes I need to make. I'm grabbing the stripe_price_id that is associated with that product and grabbing the price that way which is saved into my db directly from stripe. So that price couldn't be changed unless they tamper with my db if I'm correct. That extra params I'm passing is outdated now